# Working with bits. Overflow

Tags: c, bit

```
int main(void)
    {
        char x1 = 0x81;
        char x2 = 0x1;
        int a, b;
        a = x1+x2;
        b = (a>>8) & 0xFF;

        printf("a = %d, b = %d",a, b);
        return 0;
    }
```

Why do I get the results a = -126 and b = 255 ?

x1 is 1000 0001

x2 is 0000 0001

Sum = 1000 0010, thus it's 130. But, because it's the case with "char", 130 exceeds the maximum possible value represented on 8 bit (128). 
What can I do in this case ? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use `unsigned char`?

Comment: @haccks So is the exercise. It's required to determine the result without using computer

Comment: The default signedness of an untyped `char` is implementation defined: [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default). What implementation does "without using computer" use?

Answer (score 1):

1. Simply `x1+x2` is `1000 0010`
2. When the result is stored into `signed integer` the sign is extended,
   therefore `a` is  `1111 1111 1000 0010` which is `126D` in two's compliment   format. Almost all computers stores negative number in two's compliment format.
   Therefore `a` is interpreted as `-126` .
3. Now `b = (1111 1111 1000 0010 >> 8 ) & (0000 0000 1111 1111)`
   Therefore `b = 0000 0000 1111 1111 = 255D`.

Assumptions:

1. Your compiler treats integer as 32-bit.
2. Negative number is represented in 2's compliment format.

Answer (score 1):

In C by default char declaration is `signed char`**(-127 to +127)**. If you want to increase the range then you have to make it `unsigned char` **(0 to +255)**

So following code snippet will work for you

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char x1 = 0x81;
    unsigned char x2 = 0x1;
    int a, b;
    a = x1+x2;
    b = (a>>8) & 0xFF;
    printf("a = %d, b = %d",a, b);        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong. "**The implementation** shall define `char` to have the same range, representation, and behavior as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`" (ISO/IEC 9899:201x Draft, April 2011 [my emphasis]).

Answer (score 0):

Although you initialize the `signed char` variable with 0x81 it has a value that depends on its data type. The patter `0x81` is the representation of `-127`.

When you add -127 and 1 you get the sum -126. `1000 0010`

The result expires an integer promotion to the result type `signed int`. In this phase the sign is expanded to the new data type. `1111 1111 1000 0010`. The upper bits are the values that you see in `b`.